# How to change the list view item image resources by click on the right corner image on list item?

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter, listitem

I am working on the task that **change the image resources on list view item by clicking on that image** which is in list view item[**not click on list view item**]. It is like highlight the list view item using image resources.
I here by submit my Base adapter class code.

### DashListAdapter:

```
public class DashListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public static ProgressDialog progress;
    public static ListView dashListView;
    Context c;
    /* String fromdate_formated = "";
     String todate_formated = "";*/
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<DashListModel> dashRowList;


    public DashListAdapter(Context c, List<DashListModel> dashRowList, ListView dashListView) {
        this.c = c;
        this.progress = new ProgressDialog(c);
        this.dashListView = dashListView;
        this.dashRowList = dashRowList;
    }

    public DashListAdapter(Context c, List<DashListModel> dashRowList) {
        this.c = c;
        this.progress = new ProgressDialog(c);
        this.dashRowList = dashRowList;
    }
   /* public DashListAdapter(){

    }*/

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.e("size()", "size------>" + dashRowList.size());
        return this.dashRowList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return dashRowList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder dashHolder;
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_jobdetails_list, null);


        Log.e("get pos", "get pooooossss---->" + dashRowList.get(position));
        final DashListModel dashModel = dashRowList.get(position);
        dashHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

        dashHolder.bookmark_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (dashModel.getDashIsBookmarked().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                    Log.e("imgchange", " imgchange");
                    dashHolder.bookmark_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark);
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("candidate_id", SessionStores.getBullHornId(c));
                    params.put("joborder_id", dashModel.getDashId());
                    //new BookMarkTaskAdd(c, params);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                if (dashModel.getDashIsBookmarked().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    Log.e("imgchange", " imgchange");
                    dashHolder.bookmark_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_tag_img);
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("candidate_id", SessionStores.getBullHornId(c));
                    params.put("joborder_id", dashModel.getDashId());
                   // new BookMarkTaskDelete(c, params);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        });

        dashHolder.dash_company_name.setText(dashModel.getDashCompanyName());
        dashHolder.dash_position_name.setText(dashModel.getDashJobPosition());
        dashHolder.dash_posted_date.setText(dashModel.getPostedDate());
        dashHolder.dash_job_description.setText(dashModel.getDashJobDescription());
        dashHolder.dash_salary.setText(dashModel.getDashSalary() + " - " + dashModel.getDashEndSalary());
        dashHolder.dash_available_date.setText(dashModel.getFromDate() + " - " + dashModel.getEndDate());
        dashHolder.book_jobCity.setText(dashModel.getDashJobCity());
        Log.e("BookMa", " Book!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + dashModel.getDashIsBookmarked());
        if (dashModel.getDashIsBookmarked().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            Log.e("BookMark 1", " BookMaerk 1");
            dashHolder.bookmark_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark);
        } else if (dashModel.getDashIsBookmarked().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
            Log.e("BookMark 00", " BookMaerk 00");
            dashHolder.bookmark_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_tag_img);
        }

        return convertView;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {

        @Bind(R.id.book_company_name)
        TextView dash_company_name;
        @Bind(R.id.book_position_name)
        TextView dash_position_name;
        @Bind(R.id.book_posted_date)
        TextView dash_posted_date;
        @Bind(R.id.book_job_description)
        TextView dash_job_description;
        @Bind(R.id.book_salary)
        TextView dash_salary;
        @Bind(R.id.book_available_date)
        TextView dash_available_date;
        @Bind(R.id.book_jobCity)
        TextView book_jobCity;
       /* @Bind(R.id.book_jobState)
        TextView book_jobState;*/

        @Bind(R.id.sideView)
        ImageView sideView;

        @Bind(R.id.bookmark_img)
        ImageView bookmark_img;

        @Bind(R.id.noificationLayout)
        RelativeLayout noificationLayout;
        @Bind(R.id.notificationCount)
        TextView notificationCount;

        private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewLayParams;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);


        }
    }


}
```

the above code while click on the ***dashHolder.bookmark_img*** the image resource has to change from default image and respective ***Book mark API implementation*** also there for Book mark result update to server. In my code there is problem with changing image. kindly please look on my code and suggest me to get the solution. Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not changing the model data so update it from

```
            if (dashModel.getDashIsBookmarked().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                Log.e("imgchange", " imgchange");
                dashHolder.bookmark_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark);
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("candidate_id", SessionStores.getBullHornId(c));
                params.put("joborder_id", dashModel.getDashId());
                //new BookMarkTaskAdd(c, params);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (dashModel.getDashIsBookmarked().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                Log.e("imgchange", " imgchange");
                dashHolder.bookmark_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_tag_img);
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("candidate_id", SessionStores.getBullHornId(c));
                params.put("joborder_id", dashModel.getDashId());
               // new BookMarkTaskDelete(c, params);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

> To

```
            if (dashModel.getDashIsBookmarked().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                dashModel.setDashIsBookmarked("1");
                Log.e("imgchange", " imgchange");
                dashHolder.bookmark_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bookmark);
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("candidate_id", SessionStores.getBullHornId(c));
                params.put("joborder_id", dashModel.getDashId());
                //new BookMarkTaskAdd(c, params);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            if (dashModel.getDashIsBookmarked().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                dashModel.setDashIsBookmarked("0");
                Log.e("imgchange", " imgchange");
                dashHolder.bookmark_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_tag_img);
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("candidate_id", SessionStores.getBullHornId(c));
                params.put("joborder_id", dashModel.getDashId());
               // new BookMarkTaskDelete(c, params);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```